# Building a dynamic IdeaBlade connection string using EntityConnectionStringBuilder

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, devforce

ok rather than fighting with `xml` i was directed to the `EntityConnectionStringBuilder`. So here is what i have so far. The `EnityManagerFactory` calls the Create Method. Now the Create method creates and returns back an `EntityManager`, in this case called `UnionEntities`.

```
  public UnionEntities Create()
        {
            string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
            string serverName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseServer"];
            string databaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseName"];
            string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseUserName"];
            string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabasePassword"];
            bool integratedSecurity = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IntegratedSecurity"]);

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

            // Set the properties for the data source.
            sqlBuilder.DataSource = serverName;
            sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
            sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = integratedSecurity;
            sqlBuilder.UserID = userName;
            sqlBuilder.Password = password;

            // Build the SqlConnection connection string.
            string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

            // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
            EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder =
                new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

            //Set the provider name.
            entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;

            // Set the provider-specific connection string.
            entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

            // Set the Metadata location.
            entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/UnionModel.csdl|
                        res://*/UnionModel.ssdl|
                        res://*/UnionModel.msl";

            var manager = new UnionEntities();
            manager.Saving += SaveValidationHelper.SavingHandler;
            manager.DefaultQueryStrategy = QueryStrategy.DataSourceOnly;

            return manager;
        }
```

Now normally new `UnionEntities()` uses the `ConnectionString` in the `app.Config file`. How do i now tell it to use my `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` object instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement an [IDataSourceKeyResolver](http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/data-sources#HDynamicconnectionstrings) in DevForce to build or modify the connection string dynamically.  The link will take you to one topic on the DevForce Resource Center, but if you search there for "IDataSourceKeyResolver" you'll find additional information and a sample.